# NO ME INSERTA EN LA TABLA DE LOS DATOS QUE TENGO DE UN SELECT

Tags: select

Este es el select que tengo el html, este select realiza una consulta para arrojar los registros que hay en dicha tabla, los arroja pero después de seleccionar y poder insertar no me detecta nada y lo pone nulo

```
<div>                    
                 <select name="estudiante" class="form-control" data-live-search="true">
                <option     disabled selected>Seleccione un estudiante</option>
                <?php
                require_once("../modelo/modelo_estudiante.php");
                $est = new Estudiante();
                if ($resultado=$est->buscar('estudiante',null))
                {                                 
                    foreach ($resultado as $valor)
                  {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php if(isset($estudiante)) echo $estudiante?>">
                    <?php echo $valor['no_documento'];?>
                     </option></select>
                <?php                                                  
                 }
                }
                ?>
                <span class="help-block"></span>         
 
        </div>
```

y esta es la funcion de consulta que requiere en el html

```
public function buscar($tabla,$condicion)
   {
      if ($condicion==null)
      {
          
         $sql="Select * from ".$tabla;
      }
      else
      {
         $sql="Select * from ".$tabla." where ".$condicion; 
      }
       
      $resultado=$this->conec->query($sql);
      if($resultado)
      {
          return $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      }
      else
      {     
          return false;
      }
   }
```

después de que me busca esto, se le da a un botón que es este código

```
<button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit_btn" data-loading-text="Agregar....">Agregar usuario</button>
```

y ser debe ir a insertar que es este codigo en un php

```
   public function insertar($tabla,$datos)
   {
      //INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('49888312','demo','buesquelo@hotmail.com','docente');   
      $sql="insert into (valor,fecha_pago,mes,estudiante,funcionario)".$tabla."values('".$this->getValor()."','".$this->getFecha_pago()."','".$this->getMes()."','".$this->getEstudiante()."','".$this->getFuncionario()."')";
       $resultado = $this->conec->query($sql);
       if ($resultado)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else 
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
```

Me genera error y no me detecta la consulta que se realiza en el select de html
si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes incorrecta la forma de generar el `select`; prueba con (asumo tu proceso de obtención y presentación asi como validación de datos esta correcto):

```
<div>                    
   <select name="estudiante" class="form-control" data-live-search="true">
      <option     disabled selected>Seleccione un estudiante</option> <!-- Este elemento ignoro si esta bien así -->
      <?php
         require_once("../modelo/modelo_estudiante.php");
         $est = new Estudiante();
         if ($resultado=$est->buscar('estudiante',null))
         {
            foreach ($resultado as $valor)
            {
      ?>
             <option value="<?php if(isset($estudiante)) echo $estudiante?>">
                 <?php echo $valor['no_documento'];?>
                  </option>
      <?php
            }
         }

      ?>
   </select>
   <span class="help-block"></span>         
</div>
```

tenias en el `foreach` la etiqueta de cierre del `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo gracias por tu pronta respuesta, pero sigue igual, me ejecuta error a la hora de insertar los datos